gdb and thread sanitizer gcc, how to stop on warning/error
I tried to run a program compiled with thread sanitizer under gdb control. I simply want to stop if an warning/error occurs.
From How to add breakpoint when thread sanitizer reports data-race? I found
(gdb) set env TSAN_OPTIONS=halt_on_error=1
(gdb) run

but it simply change nothing, the program reports a warning and continue until the program ends normally.
I looked in the symbols list of tsan and found __tsan::ReportRace. Setting a breakpoint to it will stop but before writing the warning which is bad. Stepping through it seems not very handy as it has thousands of lines. Even using "until" did not work as expected.
Q: How to work interactive with gdb and thread sanitizer and stop on each reported error/warning.

Have you tried setting a breakpoint on __tsan_on_report instead?

@ssbssa: Looks good! Thanks! I already walked through the tsan sources and was 4 lines below where it checks for halt_on_error. That it call a function after it prints.... blindness :-) And perfect, as I can override it from my prog as it is intended for! If you make it an answer, I could accept it. It is a very useful hint, because it is a public interface as described in the source comments.

try to set a breakpoint for printing the report, (gdb) break vfprintf. It hits this point related to a TSan report.
